# Корень слова "картошка"

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Как найти корень в слове "картошка"?

Answer (score 1):

Слово на самом деле сложное. Не стоит его проверять "картофелем", поскольку чередования Ф/Ш в русском языке не существует. 
Лучше взять ряд "картошка"-"картошечный"-"картошина". Тогда в "картошка" корень "картош", к -суффикс, а - окончание.

Однако стоит помнить, что исторически картошка - один из просторечных вариантов названия картофеля, таких названий много: картопля, картофан, картоха и проч. Выделение общего корня в таких случаях часто не представляется возможным.

Comment: **кОртофель* - это сознательное написание или, всё же, ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка, конечно, спасибо. Сейчас поправлю. Просто на заре существования ресурса мне было по разным причинам непросто ловить случайные опечатки.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти корень в любом слове, надо подобрать однокоренные слова. В данном случае - картошка, картофель, картофельный... Общая часть этих слов - картоф/картош , где ф и ш чередуются. Значит, корень в Вашем слове - картош.

Comment: В слове "картофель" корень "картофель". Никаких чередований.